# Fancybox 2.0.5 hideOnContentClick

Tags: fancybox

How can I use hideOnContentClick in fancybox 2.0.5?

'hideOnContentClick': true

Thanks

Comment: http://fancybox.net/api has `hideOnContentClick`, but http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs doesn't, and I think fancybox 2.0.5 is from the latter, possibly meaning the support for `hideOnContentClick` has been dropped.

Answer (score 3):

Fancybox v2.x are new and not compatible with previous versions. `hideOnContentClick` has been replaced by `closeClick`. If you also want to prevent closing fancybox when clicking on the overlay, then use the `helpers` => `overlay` => `closeClick` option like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
  closeClick  : false,
  helpers   : { 
   overlay : {closeClick: false}
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: I'd like the fancybox closed after displaying the images as in the previous version

Comment: I did a test with version 2.0.6 and it worked.
--------------------------------------------------------------
### Version 2.0.6 - April 16, 2012

* Fixed #188 - keystrokes in contenteditable
* Fixed #171 - non-images should not be preloaded
* Fixed #158 - 'closeClick: true' breaks gallery navigation
* ....